# Do not record key presses when pressed in GHUB/Logitech Gaming Software

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

I made this script with LUA in GHUB:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
        PressKey("r")
        Sleep(math.random(30, 100))
        ReleaseKey("r")
        Sleep(math.random(30, 100))
    end
end
```

But I don't want mouse button 5 to be detected.
In fact, if I try to press it, it will record the pressure of key 5 and then it starts the script.
Is there a way to press the key without it being detected?

[You can open this image to understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpoXQ.png)

I thought that to do this I could create a macro instead of a script but I need a random delay. How can I solve?

Comment: `I don't want mouse button 5 to be detected` - Why is it a problem?  Just make sure your game does not have MB#5 assigned to some action.  It can be done in the game control settings.  So, the game will ignore MB#5, you can press it as much as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood you correctly, but this is the obvious steps:

1. Check `event` and `arg` in the script instead of `IsMouseButtonPressed`:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
        PressKey("r")
        Sleep(math.random(30, 100))
        ReleaseKey("r")
    end
end
```

2. If you want to disable Mouse Button 5 be "detected" when you press it:
   Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen).
   Unassign standard command "Forward" from physical MB#5 (click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu).
   Disabled MB#5 will look like a white circle with black inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried and it works!
I wanted to ask you a question at this point, could you tell me the difference between writing "IsMouseButtonPressed (5)" and "event ==" MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED "and arg == 5"?

Comment: The second way is processing only the MB#5 press event.  The first way is processing all events while MB#5 is down (for example, try to press Right Mouse Button while keeping MB#5 down - it will also simulate `R` press/release)